# different outputs from different browsers even if reset.css is applied

Tags: html, css

[image: This is the output]
It is in inline style, Why do different browsers present the same site differently?

here is the css snippet

```
.label-input, .label-input label, .label-input input , .label-input select , .label-input span {
float: left;
display: inline;
margin-left: 5px;
}

.label-input{
margin-right:5px;
}

.label-input label{
line-height: 25px;
display: inline-block;
width: 118px;
}

.label-input select{
margin-right: auto;
}
```

[here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85SVv/)

Comment: Could you show us the html as well please? maybe inside a jsfiddle ? it might be due to the `float:left` on the input depending on your html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a clearfix after you float the elements.
After each row, you need to apply the clearfix.

CSS:

```
/**
 * @info Clearfix: clear all the floated elements
 */
.clearfix:after {
    visibility:hidden;
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    content:" ";
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
.clearfix {display:inline-table;}

/**
 * @hack Display the Clearfix as a block element
 * @hackfor Every browser except IE for Macintosh
 */
    /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
    * html .clearfix {height:1%;}
    .clearfix {display:block;}
    /* End hide from IE-mac */
```

HTML:

```
// Row
<div>
    // Floated Div 1
    <div></div>
    // Floated Div 2
    <div></div>
    // ...
    // ...
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>

// Row
<div>
    // Floated Div 1
    <div></div>
    // Floated Div 2
    <div></div>
    // ...
    // ...
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Also, it'll be better if you can use Normalize.css: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/
It resets the CSS for all the browsers and it's well-maintained.

Answer (score 0):

```
float: left;
display: inline;
```

this cause the next div to come up into previous line when there is space. remove them would solve the problem. by the way font sizes vary on different browsers so make sure give enough space for the label to display in one line for different browsers.

Comment: take away these two styles from .label-input, .label-input label, .label-input input , .label-input select , .label-input span {
}

Answer (score 0):

I have add clear:both property for the label-input field. Now it is showing correctly on both the browser.

```
.label-input{
margin-right:5px;
 clear:both;
}
```